# Install zip extension in MAMP Pro

Tags: php, mamp, pecl, mamp-pro

I am running MAMP Pro and trying to install the zip extension, and am getting the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro:bin michaelharrison$ pecl install zip
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading zip-1.15.5.tgz ...
Starting to download zip-1.15.5.tgz (286,794 bytes)
............................................................done: 286,794 bytes
14 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20170718
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-michaelharrisonllhfLo/zip-1.15.5
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/zip/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
checking for PHP prefix... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1
checking for PHP includes... -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking for zip archive read/writesupport... yes, shared
checking libzip... yes
checking PHP version... 7.0/7.1/7.2
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for libzip... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/zip/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/php-config' failed
MacBook-Pro:bin michaelharrison$
```

It looks like I am missing the `libzip distribution` but I can't find info on how to fix this issue. I need the zip extension to install a Statamic addon.
I am not sure where to go from here.... any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First sorry for my English, I am Brazilian and I have no practice in writing.

I have MAMP PRO installed on version 5.5.1 with PHP 7.2.21
I checked the "Make this version available on the command line" option.

At the command line I went to the folder
 "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.21/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/"
and ran the command `pecl install zip` and the installation was successful.

I edited the *php.ini* file via Mamp PRO and enabled the extension:
`extension=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.21/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/zip.so`

I disabled the XDebug extension.

I restarted the MAMP service.

**Checking PHP version:**
At the command prompt I ran php -v

PHP 7.2.21 (cli) (built: Aug 14 2019 16:40:59) (NTS)
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

**Checking ZIP Library Version**
php --re zip | grep zip
Extension [ extension # 47 zip version 1.15.4] {

When executing command `laravel new <name>` the zip library error continued.

```
Error
The Zip PHP extension is not installed. Please install it and try again.
```

To solve I forced the version of PHP executed by the laravel command

`vim ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel`

I changed the first line from `#!/usr/bin/env php` to `#!/usr/bin/env /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.21/bin/php`

This worked well here.

I hope it helped you.